# Do I need multiple db instances in Aurora cluster for write?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have a Aurora postgresql cluster in AWS and have one DB instance in this cluster. The postgresql DB is only used for `write` not for `read`. I use it as a backup database. I know Aurora has read scaling policy and I can create multiple DB instances in this cluster to improve read performance. But it doesn't benefit my case (write only). My question is that is there any benefits for me to spin up multiple db instances in the cluster. Aurura postgresql is a single master mode which means only one instance can take write. If I deploy multiple instances/replicas, they are basically useless. Do I understand it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. In your case there is no reason to launch additional instances in the cluster.

In the future, you may be able to use Aurora multi-master to give you more performance for writes. This is only available for MySQL 5.6 at the moment. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-multi-master.html

Comment: how about failure case? If I provision 3 instances, one for write, two for read. And if the writer is down, will the aurora cluster bring one of the read to be write?

Comment: Yes. If you are worried about a slow recovery if there is a failover then a second instance will speed that up. That setup is the equivalent of Multi-AZ in non-Aurora databases. The benefit in Aurora is that you can read from the standby instance, which is not possible in non-Aurora Multi-AZ.